# What Does "Given" Mean In The Context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Metaphysics presupposes that each thing has its own fixed nature, its
> own fixed properties, and considers each thing by itself, in
> isolation. It tries to settle the nature and properties of each thing
> as a **given**, separate object of investigation, not considering things
> in their interconnection and in their change and development.

From Materialism and the Dialectical Method (Maurice Cornforth)

What does "given" mean in the context? "particular" or "already arranged"

(https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/given)

Comment: It does indeed mean "particular" or something like "identified in the particular context"

Comment: It's a noun, not an adjective: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/given_3

Comment: @Joachim: _given_ can be a noun, but in this example, it is clearly an adjective qualifing "object of investigation"

Comment: @ColinFine An adjective with an article? Are you sure? :)

Comment: Yes. If it is a noun, then you have a NP _a given_ followed by a nominal _separate object of investigation_, which is grammatically incoherent. The NP is _a given, separate object of investigation_. It's not clear to me whether _given_ modifies _separate object of investigation_, or whether _given_ and _separate_ independently modify _object of investigation_.

Comment: @ColinFine I agree entirely with you. I think that the comma requires "given" and "separate" to be in series (not nested).

Answer (score 1):

In this kind of context, '*given*' means:

> Granted as a supposition; acknowledged or assumed.

This probably could have been answered with a dictionary but it does have quite a broad definition and I can see how it might not be so obvious. By this definition a '*given*' could be a previously established fact or an obvious assumption - facts and assumptions couldn't be more different in most contexts.